# I need help writing and implementing a function into my current code

Tags: python

## This block of code will determine if you want chicken.

```
def main():

    c = 10
    print("Welcome to Roderick's Chikkin and Gravy")
    e = False
    while not e:
        x = input("Would you like some chikkin?: ")
        gravy = input('Would you like some gravy?: ')
        if gravy =="Y" or gravy == "y":
          print('You get some chikkin and gravy!')
          print("Got you some gravy!    Enjoy")
        if x == "Y" or x == "y":
            c = f(c)
            e = True
        elif c == 0:
            e = True
        else:
          e = True
          c=0
          c = f(c)
    print("I hope you enjoyed your meal!")
```

## This block of code tells outputs the final word response.

```
def f(c):

    if c > 0:
        print("Got you some chikkin!  Enjoy")
        return c-1
    else:
        print("No chikkin left.  Sorry")
        return 0

main()
```

Write a simple function named startingChikkin() that has no parameters and just asks the user for how much chikkin we start with. If the user types a positive integer, then return that value. If not, prompt again repeatedly until they enter a positive integer which you then return (see earlier sections on input validation) - the loop should be inside of your function. Call startingChikkin() at the start of the main() program and store the value returned into whatever you called your variable for tracking the number of chikkins left.

Comment: You need to be clearer on what problems you're having and what you've attempted so far, not just a code dump and clear copy-paste of a homework assignment.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree fully with the other comments, I was bored so I mad a workable version of your code. It isn't entirely what you wanted but you should be able to learn from it if nothing else.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu Oct 10 21:49:42 2019

@author: Tom
"""

def prog():
    c = start()
    print("Welcome to Roderick's Chikkin and Gravy")
    e = True
    while e:
        x = input("Would you like some chikkin?: ").upper()
        gravy = input('Would you like some gravy?: ').upper()
        if gravy =="Y":
          print('You get some chikkin and gravy!')
          print("Got you some gravy!    Enjoy")

        if x == "Y":
            e = False
            if c > 0:
                print("Got you some chikkin!  Enjoy")
                c = c - 1
            else:
                print("No chikkin left.  Sorry")
        else:
            e == False

def start():
    true = True
    while true:
        c = int(input('NO. : '))
        if c < 1:
            print('Error')
        else:
            true = False
    return c

def main():
    prog()

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

In the future please be clearer with what you have tried (instead of just posting your code) and what your problem is. This is a simple problem. Here are some of the points you can get from the description:

- The description makes it clear that you need a function called
  `startingChikkin` that takes no parameters.
- It also tells you that the function should ask for input,
  specifically it should keep asking until you get positive integers.
  From this you know that it should ask for input and that you should
  check if the input is a positive integer, if it isn't keep asking for
  input.
- It also tells you that your function should return this positive
  integer and that you `startingChikkin` function should have a loop.
  The loop is required since you want to keep asking for user input
  until it is correct.
- Finally it tells you you should call `startingChikkin` from your main
  function and use the return value to calculate the remaining
  chickens. This implies you should have a variable with the number of
  available chickens and a variable with the chickens the user wants,
  which you should get from `startingChikkin`.

From these points you can come up with something like this:

```
def startingChikkin():
    isPositiveInteger = False
    want = -1
    print("Welcome to Roderick's Chikkin and Gravy")
    while not isPositiveInteger:
        user_input = input("Would you like some chikkin?: ")
        try:
            user_input = int(user_input)
        except:
            print("Invalid Input. Please enter a positive Integer.")
        else:
            if user_input > 0:
                want = user_input
                isPositiveInteger = True
            else:
                print("Invalid Input. Please enter a positive Integer.")
    return want


def main():
    chickens = 10
    want = startingChikkin()
    if want > 0:
        print("Chickens in stock: ", chickens)
        print("Chickens in demand: ", want)
        print("Chickens remaining: ", chickens-want)
    else:
        print("Something went wrong!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```